# Остановка выполнения скриптов сайта из пользовательского скрипта

Tags: javascript

Интересует, как при выполнении пользовательского скрипта остановить выполнение всех остальных скриптов сайта.

Задача примерно следующая: есть пользовательский скрипт-робот, который заполняет формы и кликает кнопочки, на сайте есть таймеры, скриптовые, которые, доходя до нуля, обновляют страницу, так вот надо, чтобы эти таймеры замерли и дали спокойно работать пользовательскому скрипту.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вам поможет [аналогичный вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847121/how-can-i-disable-all-settimeout-events).
С другой сторогы можно попробовать отключить JavaScript в браузере и реализовать выполнение нужных действий через аддон/расширение браузера (они тоже пишутся на JS, по крайней мере для FF и Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Если страница ваша, то проще всего переопределить функцию, обновляющую страницу.

Обновление страницы:

```
var enabled = true;

function refresh() {
    if (enabled) {
        location.reload(true);
    }
}
```

Установка таймера:

```
setTimeout(refresh, timeout);
```

Запрет обновления:

```
enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов решения проблемы:

1. Заставьте ваш скрипт работать мгновенно.
2. Каждую секунду увеличивайте таймеры (если они завязаны на innerHTML) или параметры таймеров (в Ogame, например, таймеры тикали в зависимости от title таймера).
3. Попробуйте выполнить ошибочный код - а вдруг он застопорит выполнение всех скриптов?

В общем, смотреть надо в зависимости от ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

> на сайте есть таймеры, скриптовые, которые, доходя до нуля, обновляют страницу, так вот надо, чтобы эти таймеры замерли и дали спокойно работать

1. Переопредели функции `setTimeout` и `setInterval` на пустые.
2. При необходимости в цикле, например, до 1000, выполни `clearTimeout` и `clearInterval`.